# xform maxlength for input field not working on binding to integer type

Tags: xforms, orbeon

I have a requirement to limit the maxlength of an integer field to 10 digits.
But it seems like if we bind the type to integer, the maxlength is not working for input field.

```
<xforms:bind id="int-field" nodeset="instance('prepop')/type/int-field" type="xs:integer"/>

<xforms:input bind="int-field" xxforms:maxlength="10">
<xforms:alert>Required</xforms:alert>
</xforms:input>
```

And if I remove that type="xs:integer" from the bind, the maxlength works fine.

Please suggest me an alternative?

Comment: See my response below: if it isn't working in your case because you have something slightly different than the full example I posted, I'll let you update your question—posting a full example is always better—and also don't forget to add a comment to my response so I get a notification from Basecamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be working fine with the latest nightly build, and the following full example:

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
      xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
      xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner">
    <xhtml:head>
        <xhtml:title>Input bound to integer node with maxlength attribute</xhtml:title>
        <xforms:model>
            <xforms:instance>
                <instance>123</instance>
            </xforms:instance>
            <xforms:bind nodeset="." type="xs:integer"/>
        </xforms:model>
    </xhtml:head>
    <xhtml:body>
        <xforms:input ref="." xxforms:maxlength="10">
            <xforms:alert>Required</xforms:alert>
        </xforms:input>
    </xhtml:body>
</xhtml:html>
```

Comment: Thanks Vernet. Let me try to see it in the next stable release of Orbeon.

Comment: FYI, the 3.9 RC 1 was released 2 days ago, so you might want to test this one out. http://blog.orbeon.com/2011/03/orbeon-forms-390-release-candidate-1.html

Comment: Hey thanks Vernet for the info. I was able to successfully install the war in my Websphere. I will test my issues and let you know

Comment: Excellent, I am glad it worked on WebSphere. Thank you for the update.